# Rails 4.2 Active Job Resque Enqueue Undefined Method Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, resque, rails-activejob

I am following https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/getting-started-with-active-job to implement Active Job in Rails 4.2. But faced with the following issue in Resque. Error reads:

```
Worker
ChickenSmitten.local:64238 on EMAIL at just now Retry or Remove
Class
 ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::ResqueAdapter::JobWrapper
Arguments
---
job_class: PasswordResetJob
job_id: 35f70043-9a9b-4add-8700-a5f388350fb4
queue_name: email
arguments:
- bob@example.com
Exception
NoMethodError
Error
undefined method `email' for "bob@example.com":String
```

My codes are below:

password_resets_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:password_reset][:email].downcase)
    if @user
      @user.create_reset_digest
      @user.send_password_reset_email
      flash[:notice] = "Email sent with password reset instructions"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Email address not found"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

user.rb

```
  def send_password_reset_email
    PasswordResetJob.new(self.email).enqueue(wait: 10.seconds)
  end
```

app/jobs/password_reset_job.rb

```
class PasswordResetJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :email

  def perform(email)
    UserMailer.password_reset(email).deliver_now
  end
end
```

app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@example.com"

  def password_reset(user)
    @user = user
    mail to: user.email, subject: "Password Reset"
  end

end
```

Somehow, "self.email" from user.rb is not passed to password_reset_job.rb. Hence, error "undefined method `email' for "bob@example.com":String".

Thanks in advance.

#### UPDATE

Pursuant to Prakash's advice and making one more change as below, changed "self.email" to "self":

```
  def send_password_reset_email
    PasswordResetJob.new(self).enqueue(wait: 10.seconds)
  end
```

A new error popped. Here is the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"password_resets", :email=>"bob@example.com", :format=>nil, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Below are more details that may help.

```
[2] pry(#<User>)> PasswordResetJob.new(self).enqueue(wait: 10.seconds)
[ActiveJob] Enqueued PasswordResetJob (Job ID: 6bdcca3c-367d-48ea-b3c9-1f5378e5df57) to Resque(email) at 2015-01-06 04:58:28 UTC with arguments: gid://affiliation/User/1
=> #<PasswordResetJob:0x007fbd4c028dc8
 @arguments=
  [#<User:0x007fbd4b686590
    id: 1,
    username: "bob",
    email: "bob@example.com",
    password_digest: "$2a$10$dbbEBwNgBtaZEvtl7EsUm./hdukr3MMKlUWdouV3RwIFMmMPfR6CS",
    created_at: Thu, 01 Jan 2015 03:38:54 UTC +00:00,
    updated_at: Tue, 06 Jan 2015 04:58:01 UTC +00:00,
    role: "admin",
    slug: "bob",
    activation_digest: "$2a$10$wdoO7vn5Ng4U4TEPCmqVFeVYAB8sZ2CKEpVFfduYyD7Ee.NfvSRsi",
    activated: true,
    activated_at: Thu, 01 Jan 2015 03:41:19 UTC +00:00,
    remember_digest: nil,
    reset_digest: "$2a$10$Eu1jYllohAY2IQO4Uc.0TuyNmRWWuu3jQgjZrIZLwFlo1t8n1hNZO",
    reset_sent_at: Tue, 06 Jan 2015 04:58:01 UTC +00:00,
    url: "www.google.com",
    bio: "Woo ga shaka.">],
 @job_id="6bdcca3c-367d-48ea-b3c9-1f5378e5df57",
 @queue_name="email",
 @scheduled_at=1420520308.6658938>
```

views/user_mailer/password_reset.html.rb

```
<h1>Password reset</h1>

<p>To reset your password click the link below:</p>

<%= link_to "Reset password", edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token,
                                                      email: @user.email) %>

<p>This link will expire in two hours.</p>

<p>
If you did not request your password to be reset, please ignore this email and
your password will stay as it is.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the email to PasswordResetJob which passes it to the mailer but the mailer expects a User instance.

PS: you can do directly UserMailer.password_reset(self.email).deliver_later in the model. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html#method-i-deliver_later

Comment: Your answer helped me resolved the problem stated in this question, but a new error cropped up as shown in update above. I suppose the new error should be asked as a new question. Will see what I can do. In the meanwhile, do let me know if can help on this error. I am most grateful. Thanks. =)

Comment: In the edit_password_reset_url the route helper expects :id while the :id is nil. The :id is the first parameter so this probably means that "@user.reset_token" is nil

Comment: True, perhaps that would be the case, here are some other observations that might help.

(1) if I dont use background jobs and just use "UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver" in "def send_password_reset_email", whilst all other code remains the same, there will be no error and the email will be sent. But of course, that is not the best way.

(2) It is even tougher as I cant pry "/password_reset.html.rb" even with remote pry. Any thoughts on how I can do this? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
def perform(email)
  UserMailer.password_reset(email).deliver_now
end
```

This is calling the `password_reset` method in `UserMailer` with `email` (which has the value of `bob@example.com` in this specific case.

```
def password_reset(user)
  @user = user
  mail to: user.email, subject: "Password Reset"
end
```

So within `password_reset` method, `user` is getting set to `bob@example.com`, and hence failing when `user.email` is called.

One way to fix this would be to make the method as follows:

app/mailers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@example.com"

  def password_reset(email)
    mail to: email, subject: "Password Reset"
  end

end
```

You might have to find a different way based on the specific needs.

Comment: Hey thanks. the error is no longer present, but I am faced with a new error, ActionView::Template::Error
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"password_resets", :email=>"bob@example.com", :format=>nil, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]. I have updated my post for this, error.

Comment: Please create a new question for a new problem; not a good practice to update an existing question with the next issue that comes up.

Comment: Agreed. Will post it up soon.